# How can i Use a token generated in the next thread in Jmeter

Tags: automation, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have extracted the authorization token after running my login API successfully. And it can be used within the same thread while I'm configuring different HTTP requests.

But I want to create a separate thread for rest of my APIs and use the authorization token which I extracted already. How can I do it in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

According to [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads

So you can pass it in 2 ways:

1. Using [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function in 1st Thread Group (or thread) to store the value into a JMeter Property and then use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to read it back where required.
2. Using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) if your logic is more complex